# iphone development: iterate loop when a button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, while-loop, iteration

In my iPhone app, I have a while loop in viewDidLoad. I have four buttons in my view.

I want to make the while loop to iterate if one of the four buttons is pressed.

Lets say;

```
int k = 0;
while (k<4){

     if (// one of the buttons is pressed...){
         k++;
     }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

edit: I tried this but it did not work:

```
 int k = 0;
    while (k<4){

         if ([self.answerButton_1 isSelected]){
             k++;
         }

    }
```

Comment: "it did not work" does not help us at all. Please be more specific.

Comment: @janusfidel Nope I did not want to know which button is pressed. I just want to increase "k" value only if one of the buttons is pressed

Comment: are you just trying to know which button is pressed? if yes , 

    -(void)yourMethod:(UIButton*)pressedButton
    {
        if(pressedButton.tag == x){
            k++;
        }
    }

**this is a second comment in thread that was answered.

Comment: @sosborn well it simply did not work. the screen become frozen. Does not react anything.

Comment: "the screen become frozen" That helps us a lot. You've got an infinite loop because your answerButton_1 is not selected. You really should not poll for those kind of changes anyway. Just react appropriately when the button is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the method **viewDidLoad** is only called once, when the app starts, but you want to do something later when someone presses a button.

You need to have the button call a method when it's pressed. So you need to do a few things

1) in the header, you need to add the variable k so it will be available in all your functions:

```
int k;
```

2) create a button in your viewDidLoad:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
      action:@selector(someoneTouchedYourButton)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"add to k" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

3) set the initial value of k, in the viewDidLoad will be OK

```
k = 0;
```

3) create the function that gets called when someone presses the button:

```
-(void) someoneTouchedYourButton
{
    k ++;
    NSLog(@"someone pressed the button. k is now %d",k);
}
```

4) you seem to want to limit k to a maximum of 4, so add something in the someoneTouchedYourButton section to limit it to 4.

```
if(k > 4)
{
     k = 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it looks like what I am looking for. However I didn't get the fourth part.

Comment: In your question you had the line "while (k<4)". I assumed this meant you only wanted k to go up to 4. if you want K to keep increasing past 4, then you don't need to worry about part 4.

Also, if it worked it'd be great of you could accept my answer!

Answer (score 0):

That's a wierd way of doing it. The while loop will be blocking the main thread and you will not be able to get any UI input. You should use a IBAction and hook up the button through interface builder (or programmatically) and use tags for each button.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id) sender {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        int tag = [button tag];
        //Do what you need to depending on "tag"
}
```